# Insert a row with no value to get the generated id

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to insert a row so i can get the generated id.

I have a table named "TypeOfDog" with the column "id: smallserial" (auto generated id). 
I have another table named "TypeOfDogLang" with the column "id: smallint" (pk + fk to id of TypeOfDog), "lang" (pk) and "name" (the name in different language).

```
+-----------------------+
|       TypeOfDog       |
+-----------------------+
| id | smallserial | pk |  <-- Insert here
+----+-------------+----+

+--------------------------+
|       TypeOfDogLang      |
+--------------------------+
| id   | smallint | pk, fk |
+------+----------+--------+
| lang | text     | pk     |
+------+----------+--------+
| name | text     | nn     |
+------+----------+--------+
```

I want to insert a row in "TypeOfDog" without forcing the id so it can be auto generated by the DB.

Something like `INSERT INTO "TypeOfDog" (NULL) VALUES (NULL) RETURNING id;`

I'm using postgreSQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO "TypeOfDog" VALUES (default) RETURNING id;
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more tests I figured out a way to do it.

You can't insert a row without specifying a column and a value. To bypass this and instert the row without forcing the id, i used the **DEFAULT** keyword.

Here's the sql: `INSERT INTO "TypeOfDog" VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING id;`

Hope this helps others.